# Even and Odd Maps in Group Homomorphism

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, permutations, group-isomorphism, group-homomorphism

I'm curious about a particular property in a group homomorphism. Suppose that $\phi:S_{6}\rightarrow\mathbb{Z}_{2}$ is any map, not necessarily a group homomorphism, with $(S_{6},\circ)$ and $(\mathbb{Z},+)$ are groups and $S_{6}=\{\sigma_{k}\mid k\in[1,6!]\cap\mathbb{Z}\}$ and $\mathbb{Z}_{2}=\{[0]_{2},[1]_{2}\}$. Then, I want to find a particular $\phi$ such that $\phi$ is a group homomorphism. In some sense, it is straightforward that I can assume a map $\phi$ such that each $\sigma_{2k}\mapsto[0]_{2}$ and each $\sigma_{2k+1}\mapsto[1]_{2}$. For such $\phi$, how can I proof that it is indeed a group homomorphism?

Comment: Did you use $\cong$ to mean "isomorphic"? Also, you probably know that an " onto" homomorphism $\phi$ would only guarantee $\mathbb Z_2\cong (S_6)/\ker\phi$. Finally, the way you defined $\phi$ it may or may not be a homomorphism (it is really an arbitrary map) so I am not sure what you want to conclude from _that_. Aside, two groups are either isomorphic or not, there is no such thing as "isomorphic for such-and-such $\phi$".

Comment: To expand on the previous comment: two groups are isomorphic if _there exists_ an isomorphism map of one to the other. The fact you put the logical quantifier "there exists" $(\exists)$ means that the notion of being isomorphic does not depend on that map. An analogous example: an integer $n$ is _even_ if there exists an integer $k$ such that $n=2k$. Surely $6$ is even (as $6=2k$ for $k=3$) but it does not make sense to ask if "$6$ is even for $k=3$" any more than it makes sense to ask if $6$ is even for $k=7$, i.e. does not make sense at all. $6$ is even, full stop.

Comment: For the latter we usually use the word "witness" in math. You can ask, knowing that $6$ is even: is $k=3$ a witness that proves that $6$ is even? Yes. Is $k=7$ a witness? No. Back to your question: even if your groups $S_6$ and $\mathbb Z_2$ _were_ isomorphic, a random map $\phi$ would be a _witness_ of that fact only if it is indeed an isomorphism.

Comment: @StinkingBishop Yes, you are correct. My bad for the unedited question. However,  I do agree with you, i.e., a random map $\phi$ would be a witness of two isomorphic groups if it is indeed a group isomorphism. Thank you for the enlightenment. Now, I have edited my question. I'm wondering if you could me with that by any chance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The question having been clarified, I can write a more appropriate answer. I'll leave my no-longer-relevant answer at the bottom, so the comments will still make some sense.

There are two, and only two, homomorphisms from $S_6$ to ${\bf Z}_2$. One of them takes every element of $S_6$ to zero, but that's not the one you want. The other one must take to zero a subgroup of $S_6$ of index two in $S_6$ (and take all the other elements of $S_6$ to the element $1$ in ${\bf Z}_2$).

Now, $S_6$ has only one subgroup of index two (that is, one subgroup containing exactly half the elements of $S_6$), and that is the alternating group $A_6$. $A_6$ consists of the "even" elements of $S_6$, that is, the elements that can be written as products of an even number of transpositions. This is easily seen to be a subgroup, as it contains the identity, and the product of two products of an even number of transpositions is a product of an even number of transpositions, likewise for the inverse.

To be specific, the elements of $A_6$ are the $3$-cycles, of which there are $40$; the $5$-cycles, of which there are $144$; the products of two disjoint $3$-cycles, of which there are $40$; the products of two disjoint transpositions, of which there are $45$; the products of a transposition and a disjoint $4$-cycle, of which there are $90$; and the identity element; all told, $40+144+40+45+90+1=360$.

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

No, the symmetric group on six letters is not isomorphic to the cyclic group of order two, no matter what map $\phi$ you come up with. For one thing, in order for two groups to be isomorphic, they must have the same number of elements, which these two groups patently do not.

Comment: I doubt that isomorphism was intended. I think the OP means $$S_6/A_6\cong\Bbb Z_2.$$

Comment: @Shaun, you may well be right. Let's see whether OP comes back to clarify. I can always delete my answer if OP revises the question so my answer is no longer useful.

Comment: That's fair. I deleted mine but upvoted yours.

Comment: @GerryMyerson Yes, you are correct about that. I missed that fact before. I'm back and clarified my question.